# Can I have two working pyspark versions (1.6.1 and 2.0) on my Macbook Pro at the same time?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently working with Spark 1.6.1 and use it in both Jupyter ipython notebooks and from Java 8. For Java I can just modify my maven pom to import Spark 2.0, but I'm not sure how to do the equivalent in Ipython. I think I need to install 2.0, but is that doable since I already have Spark 1.6.1 installed? Can I have both versions on my macbook and select which one to use from pyspark? how?

Update: This is how I launch my Jupyter pyspark notebook => on terminal: `% IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark`. How do I tell it to launch with Spark 2.0?

Comment: On linux, one should update the environment variable $SPARK_HOME

Answer (score 2):

> Can I have both versions on my macbook and select which one to use from pyspark

Yes.

Say you have extracted Spark to `/opt/apache-spark` folder. Then, in there, you could have both versions of `2.0.0` and `1.6.1`.

Then, to run `pyspark` of version `2.0.0`, you simply run

```
/opt/apache-spark/2.0.0/bin/pyspark
```

---

The real question you need to ask is why do you think you need both versions?

Comment: I wanted to have Spark 2.0 to learn it while I'm still using 1.6.. once I learned 2.0 I have no need for 1.6.

Comment: So, did this answer the question, then?

Comment: Not fully. I'm running Ipython notebooks. you didn't really give much detail.. are you saying when I download Spark 2.0 it will find itself to my current 1.6 directory? also, when I launch my Jupyter notebook (on terminal: IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark) how do I tell it to launch with Spark 2.0?

Comment: I don't know how you downloaded Spark. Jupyter notebooks weren't really part of the initial question. You simply asked if you could have 2 versions of Spark in your system, which is yes. Regarding the notebooks, though, you can have 2 pyspark or scala kernels for each version.